# Using EditorFor with IEnumerable<string> in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an IEnumerable containing strings, using Data Annotations for validation:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required.")]
[Remote("IsValid", "ControllerName")]
public IEnumerable<string> MyList { get; set; }
```

I'm then using this with an editor template. This is how I call it in my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyList)
```

Finally, my template takes this IEnumarable and creates a number of form elements for each element:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@foreach (var str in Model)
{
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => str, "My Label")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => str)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => str)
    </li>
}
```

Even though the form elements do render correctly, am I approaching this correctly? Also, I have noticed that it no longer validates. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going about it in a "correct" way. (Correct in that it can work, I have done this before) But with validation the reason I think it doens't work is this, you have the validation on the IEnemerable and not on the string.
To get validation on each string. You would have to create a new model object say

```
public class LabelString
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required.")]
    public string labelName { get; set; }
}
```

And then where you have `public IEnumerable<string> MyList { get; set; }`   replace it with `public IEnumerable<LabelString> MyList { get; set; }`

That should give you validation on each of the labels in the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Its not a math, so there's more than 1 solution to your problem and *there's no right one*.

Said that, however, I'd rather approach it differently:

```
public class StringsViewModel
{
   IEnumerable<string> myList;
}
```

In the view you'll need then

```
@model StringsViewModel
@EditorForModel()
```

It will validate **because you now have strongly typed model** rather than generic one.
Also, you save on the `foreach` loop that is done for you automagically by the framework...

Hope this helps.